# Sharepoint 2013 is creating new documents when editing office 2007 docs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-migration, document-migration, powerpoint

We have a new fresh SharePoint 2013 environment. We are in the progress of deploying it to users and we have found that migrated documents from SharePoint 2007 such as PowerPoint when edited in the browser it creates a new document in the new PowerPoint format. The problem is it leaves the old document. Is there a way to get rid of the old one when it creates the new one?

Alternatively has anyone else come across this and how did you get around it.

Comment: Is it the same behavior with word and excel files? Can you confirm they are saving and not using save a new copy

Comment: It's the same behavior with all office 2007 files yes. It is when they open the file in the OWA browser by clicking the epsilon and selecting edit.

Comment: Sorry to confirm OWA I mean office web apps (aren't Microsoft great naming things the same...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and speaking to a few people who know more than me I found that it is not possible to stop it, we have got around it somewhat by forcing download of .ppt files meaning when the user edits them they are more aware there will be 2 versions. Not perfect but it's a limitation of the software.